# grailsApplication autowiring to spock tests are always null

Tags: grails, spock

Spock tests injects null to grailsApplication,as i tried autowiring both to grails service and to domain objects(spec)

code(AttackSpec.groovy)

```
package core

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.Specification

/**
 * See the API for {@link grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin} for usage instructions
 */
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@TestFor(Attack)
class AttackSpec extends Specification {


    def grailsApplication


    def setup() {
        Attack attack = new Attack();
        println 'app '+grailsApplication.toString()
    }

    def cleanup() {

    }

    void "test something"() {
        setup:
            println 'app '+grailsApplication.toString()
    }
}
```

output

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
appnull
appnull
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/ops/grails-2.4.4/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.4.4.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/ops/grails-2.4.4/lib/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
```

I have tried using explicit @Autowired annotation and Static Typing,yet it's always the same. it seems like I have to inflate the grails application somewhere?

Comment: It is unit test so you cannot autowire.

Comment: How exactly do you run this test?

Comment: Show the actual function you want to test.

Comment: it's for a pre step , i have beans in resources.groovy i want to re-use and persist

Comment: i run the test ,in spec debug via default intellij configuration

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to be running an integration test and not a unit test. Move your class under the integrations test folder and you may need to eliminate your test class annotations because I think those are only for unit testing.

Comment: thats not what i wish to do, it's seems the answer is using "  static loadExternalBeans = true " . but still i can't get it to work ,it doesn't inject the beans defined in resources.groovy

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of injecting `grailsApplication` in a unit test?. If you want to set a config, because your class under test: `Attack` reads a value of the grails application, then you can mock the grailsApplication as following:

```
def 'test whatever you want to'() {
  def attack = new Attack()
  attack.grailsApplication = [config: [my: [setting: "myValue"]]] // if attack uses grailsApplication.config.my.setting internally

  when: 
  def setting = attack.getMySetting()

  then:
  setting == "myValue"
}
```

Or you could use a real Mock if you want to track access to it.

If you really want to use the grails environment to test, that access of the values on the framework (for whatever reason that might be) is correct executed, you should use an integration test. Subclassing IntegrationSpec from Spock will inject the grailsApplication into your test, so you can set the real thing in your `Attack` class.

Comment: i need to read an Attack from database, i have defined a bean which should be persisted and read for tests, now can you explain the first sentence? how are the alternatives better? writing the data anywhere outside AttackSpec may yield data inconsistency or unwanted data in db or even fail my test as it is non self-contained test,if anyone messes up a variable or some other setup test.this way i do  tear up and tear down cleaning the db , in a non global setup env. i will try your solution though.

Comment: the first sentence just means, that the normally a unit test is something, that does not depend on anything than the unit you want to test (in oo-languages this literally means "the class"). This is because of the isolation that you want to achieve in the test. Due to this, all dependencies are cut off (which i did with given the attack class a stub implementation for the grailsApplication dependency). I'm not sure if i'm getting something wrong here, were does the domain class uses the grailsApplication? Perhaps you have to show some more code here...

Comment: Hey David, it's just another way to inflate\instanciate and persist attack instance, so instead of using -> attack =  new Attack() ... ,I use a predefined bean,grailsApplication has no connection to Attack class nor is it explicitly autowired there in any way.